# Positional indexing error in scipy minimization of a function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to minimize the return value of a function by optimizing its variable. The variable indicates the lenght of a rolling window so that the function is always using the last #window values in the series that I'm considering.

This is the function:

```
def func(window):
  beta = []
  for acca in range(1100,len(var1)):
    result = sm.OLS(var1.iloc[acca-window:acca], sm.add_constant(var2.iloc[acca-window:acca])).fit()
    beta.append(result.params[1]);
  beta_to_plot = np.array(beta)
  return beta_to_plot.max()-beta_to_plot.min()
```

var1 and var2 are 2 series with 1470 rows each

And it returns the difference between the max and the min in the array that is generated.

```
import scipy.optimize as spop
spop.minimize(func, 100)
```

And I get this error

```
cannot do positional indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [[1000.]] of type ndarray
```

What am i doing wrong? How can I achieve what i want?

Comment: What does the `var1` look like?

Comment: var1 and var2 are 2 series with 1470 rows each

Comment: What's the full traceback?  I'm guessing the problem is in the `var1` or `var2` indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj excuse my ignorance, what do you mean by traceback?

Comment: What's the full error?  For some reason beginners like to quote just one line, ignoring the information tell them/us **where** the error occurs.  That 'where' is important.